# missing wm_lbuttondown under windows 8 touchscreen

Tags: delphi, dll, windows-8, touch, mouse

i have a self written windows control, written in c++ / mfc42 / visual studio 6. the control is derived from a CStatic control and reacts to wm_lbuttondown / wm_lbuttonup. the control is compiled into an dll. the dll is loaded dynamically into an application that is written in delphi 7. so far everything is working / worked ok for years (under win xp / vista / win 7).

the problem is: under windows 8 on an acer iconia w3-810 when i touch the control via touchscreen the control does not receive the wm_lbuttondown / wm_lbuttonup messages.
when you click the control with the mouse, everything works as expected, only touch does not work.

additionally: this only happens when the control is used inside the dll. when i try it with a standalone version of the control (a .exe file without the need for an external dll) then the control does receive the wm_lbuttondown / wm_lbuttonup messages when i touch it.

when i try it under a windows 7 touchscreen device (some lenovo) it works correctly via touch!

another info: when i touch the control under win 8 i do get other undocumented messages instead of wm_lbuttondown / wm_lbuttonup... the messagecodes are (decimal) 585, 582, 581, 583 and 586...

has anybody an idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Perhaps down to a 15+ year old MFC. Why don't you use modern tooling.

Comment: Your undocumented messages are a little bit close to WM_TOUCH. I can't think of anything to speculate though..

Comment: Thanks, I now found that the messages are WM_POINTERENTER, WM_POINTERDOWN, WM_POINTERUPDATE, WM_POINTERUP, WM_POINTERLEAVE

Comment: @user - Good find. Even they have a name, they are indeed quite [undocumented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn280599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Problem. The Delphi wrapper code for the DLL-control was setting another WndProc for the DLL-control and in this new WndProc was a call to DefWindowProc that was causing the problems under Windows 8/Touchscreen.